# Convert Twitter New Date Format to Date Time ( %Y-%m-%d %H:%M%S' )

Tags: python, date, time, twitter

Twitter's new date format used to be

```
%a %b %d %H:%M%S    0000 %Y
```

Now however it is like this...

```
df.created_at[0]
   '2021-03-08T19:14:00.000Z'
```

How do we convert that?  What is confusing me is figuring out how to process the "T" and the ".000Z" portions.

Thanks!

E :

To be clear, https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/timezones says what the strptime is.  However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

Trying my best guess...

```
datetime.strftime( datetime.strptime( df.created_at[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00%z' ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
ValueError: time data '2021-03-08T19:14:00.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00%z'
```

Trying their exact match...

```
datetime.strftime( datetime.strptime( df.created_at[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S%z' ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
ValueError: 'l' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S%z'
```

Comment: this is a standard ISO format. you can just use datetutils.Parser.parse()

Comment: parse(df.created_at[0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') did indeed work. Though I am still curious why the formatting Twitter supplied did not work.

Comment: I usually use dateutils, for simplicity, but you actually were just missing a 0 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> datetime.strftime( datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00%z' ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2021-03-08T19:14:00.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.00%z'
>>> datetime.strftime( datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000%z' ), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' )
'2021-03-08 19:14:00'
```

You were just missing a `0` in your parsing string.